# If $Z=X+Y$, and I know the probability distribution of $Z$ and $Y$, and $X\perp Y$ how to recover the probability distribution of X?

Tags: distributions, density-function, sum, deconvolution

Suppose I know the distribution of $Z$ and $Y$: $Z\sim F_Z$ with density $f_Z$, $Y\sim F_Y$ with density $f_Y$.  Suppose I also know that $Z=X+Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are independent and the distribution of $X$ is unknown. How to recover the distribution of $X$ and express it using $F_Z$ and $F_Y$ (or $f_Z$ and $f_Y$)?

Answer (score 6):

This is essentially deconvolution.

One approach would be to compute $\phi_X(t)$, the characteristic function of $X$ as $\phi_Z(t)/\phi_Y(t)$ (since the c.f. of $Z$ is the product of the c.f.s of $X$ and $Y$) and then from there compute the density of $X$.

Comment: @Ben Thanks a lot, Ben! This is very helpful! One more question, after I got the characteristic function for $X$: $\phi_X(t)=\phi_Z(t)/\phi_Y(t)$, how to compute the density of $X$ using $\phi_X(t)$?

Comment: ... :^) ... In response to your question, note that the characteristic function is in effect a Fourier transform (up to a sign-flip in the exponent); it can be inverted in analogous fashion.  Or you can work directly with Fourier transforms and their inverses if you prefer those, as described in the Wikipedia article on deconvolution.

Comment: @ExcitedSnail: This is Glen's answer --- I just made a tiny correction.

Comment: @Glen_b haha, sorry, Glen_b. I didn't read the editing history of your answer carefully. Your answer is very helpful. Will check out wikipedia deconvolution!